# flutter return multiple lines in json post

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a request like this

```
Future getPhoneData(User user) async {
// make request
_accname = ('${user.email}');
_useruniqid = ('${user.unique_id}');
var response;
return response = await https.post(
    "https://api.url",
    body: jsonEncode({
      "type": "simpledata",
      "account": "$_account",
      "useruniqid": "$_useruniqid"
    }));}
```

In response, the API sends me json

```
[{
"url":"test.url.com",
"password":"123"
}]
```

How do I write each element of the Json response to a variable?

example:

```
$_url = fromjsonurl;
$_password = fromjsonpassword;
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your JSON response to Model Classes online from [here](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

```
Future<List<UserModel>> getPhoneData(User user) async {
// make request
_accname = ('${user.email}');
_useruniqid = ('${user.unique_id}');
var response =  await https.post(
    "https://api.url",
    body: jsonEncode({
      "type": "simpledata",
      "account": "$_account",
      "useruniqid": "$_useruniqid"
    }));
var userList = List<UserModel>()

final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
     
     for(Map i in data){
      userList.add(UserModel.fromJson(i));
    }


return userList;
}
```

**Here is your Model response**

```
class UserModel {
  String url;
  String password;

  UserModel({this.url, this.password});

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['url'];
    password = json['password'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['password'] = this.password;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: sry,im newbee in flutter.how its use with my code? )

Comment: you can read here  => https://medium.com/flutterdevs/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-b7f991611d3e

Comment: its for get. i use post

Comment: It does not matter of GET/POST,, it's all about response. what you getting

Comment: @admin883 please check my updated answer. just copy and page

Comment: aaaand how i can use now elements from response in variable?

Comment: in php im use:

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
      $res = json_decode($data);
            $acc = $res->account;
            $niqid = $res->useruniqid;

Comment: anybody? ))) how access to values from json? ))

Comment: post you class code in you question. From where you are callling  getPhoneData(*)